# How to add text to existing text in static control in win32

Tags: c, winapi, textbox, win32gui

I am making a program in win32 c using visual studio rc and I can't figure out how to do this seemingly simple task. I have a static text control, an edit control, and a button. When the user clicks the button, I wan't the program to take the text in the edit control and add it to whatever is in the static text box. After much headache and various attempts, I still cannot get this to work. I can retrieve the text from the edit control fine, but any attempt to add it to the static control crashes. Well actually just to clarify, I can set the text fine; it's just adding to the existing text that crashes the program. Could someone please post some code that would allow me to do this using GetWindowText() and SetWindowText(), (or something else if it preferable). Here is what I have:

```
SendMessage(hwndEditControl, WM_GETTEXT,255,(LPARAM)editbuffer);
GetWindowText(hwndTextControl, (LPWSTR)allText, GetWindowTextLength(hwndTextControl));
//function to add data, please create on
SetWindowText(hwndTextControl, (LPCWSTR)allText);}
//where
static TCHAR*       editbuffer = new TCHAR; //feel free to change these declarations
static TCHAR*       allText    = new TCHAR;
```

Any help much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your buffers are one character long... Why not just a normal array?

Comment: so declare them: new TCHAR [AMOUNT]

Comment: could i dynamically allocate them with malloc

Comment: If you want to factor in the actual length, you have to, seeing as how `new` isn't C.

Comment: alright thanks. Also could you just point out where I mixed up WCHAR and TCHAR so I can fix that

Comment: Your buffers are TCHAR and you're casting them to WCHARs when you call the functions. If you're using TCHARs, they'll already be WCHARs if the function needs them like that.

Comment: Ok thanks. And also how would I add the two buffers assuming I dynamically allocated both of them with malloc. I tried using strcat_s, but it didn't work, probably because of my buffers being one character long

Comment: You should have enough memory allocated for the length of the text in the editbox in one buffer, plus one for the null, and the length of both put together (plus one) in your other buffer. You should also be using the appropriate (TCHAR) version of `strcat`.

Comment: so something that looks like strcat_s (buf1, malloc(sizeof(buf1) + sizeof(buf2) + 1), buf2); ?

Comment: If you have C99, you can use VLAs, but otherwise more like `TCHAR *editBuffer = malloc (sizeof(TCHAR) * (editboxTextLength + 1)); TCHAR *all = malloc (sizeof(TCHAR) * (editboxTextLength + staticTextLength + 1)); copyEditToEditBuffer(); copyStaticToAllBuffer(); appendEditBufferToAllBuffer();`

Comment: Ok thanks so much for the help. If you put this as an answer, I'll make sure to accept it tomarrow

Comment: I'm concerned about the casts.  They shouldn't be necessary.  If you find it necessary to cast a TCHAR* to an LPWSTR, then it's likely you've got your build environment messed up.

Comment: Yeah the casts are just leftover from my previous attempts. I forgot to get rid of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only reserving one char for your string buffers. So instead of

```
static TCHAR*       editbuffer = new TCHAR;
static TCHAR*       allText    = new TCHAR;
```

you have to reserve much more memory, e.g.:

```
static TCHAR*       editbuffer = new TCHAR[255];
static TCHAR*       allText    = new TCHAR[255];
```

which would give you string buffers that can hold 254 chars and the terminating null char.

However I would recommend that you simply reserve the memory on the stack inside your function:

```
void OnButtonClick()
{
    TCHAR editbuffer[255] = {0};
    TCHAR allText[255] = {0};
    ...
}
```